# He is unathletically built

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

He is unathletically built.

- Is this description grammatical and natural?
- Is "unathletically" unidiomatic?

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday. It was closed due to lack of details. You then made a trivial edit to it and tried to get it reopened. The reopen request was rejected because no real improvement was made. Please note: when your question gets closed, **do not** post it again in a different post to circumvent the closure. You need to look at the close reasons carefully and improve your question to bring it on-topic. As I have explained, your questions need to contain details and information. "Is this grammatical?" questions are off-topic proofreading requests.

Comment: Respectfully disagree,  the other version was unanswerable, as a word can't be idiomatic.  This is clear, has a clear focus and can't be answered by reference to dictionaries (as some do contain "unathletically").  "Is a word used correctly" is not proofreading, as a specfic concern is identified.

Comment: @JamesK Improvement acknowledged, the two posts are still the same question though and it shouldn't have been posted separately. I think generally speaking I have noticeably relaxed  "proofreading" closure. If you take a look at the review queue, I have consistently voted to keep open borderline questions. Had OP improved the original question, I wouldn't have closed it. The important thing I saw was for OP to understand what good ELL questions should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically correct.

The word unathletic is rather unusual, and the adverb "unathletically" is very odd.  Don't use it.  Just say "He isn't athletic" or "doesn't have an athletic build" (for example)